# Query Postgres table by Block Range Index (BRIN) identifier directly

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have *N* client machines. I want to load each of machine with distinct partition of BRIN index.

That requires to:

- create BRIN with predefined number of partitions - equal to number of client machines
- send queries from clients which uses *WHERE* on BRIN partitions identifier instead of filter on indexed column

The main goal is performance improvement when loading single table from postgres into distributed client machines, keeping equal number of rows between the clients - or close to equal if *rows count* not divides by *machines count*.

I can achieve it currently by maintaining new column which chunks my table into number of buckets equal to number of client machines (or use `row_number() over (order by datetime) % N` on the fly). This way it would not be efficient in timing and memory, and the BRIN index looks like a nice feature which could speed up such use cases.

Minimal reproducible example for 3 client machines:

```
CREATE TABLE bigtable (datetime TIMESTAMPTZ, value TEXT);
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-01 00:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt1');
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-01 05:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt2');
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-02 02:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt3');
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-02 03:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt4');
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-02 05:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt5');
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-02 16:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt6');
INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES ('2015-12-02 23:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'txt7');
```

Expected output:

- client 1

```
2015-12-01 00:00:00+00, 'txt1'
2015-12-01 05:00:00+00, 'txt2'
2015-12-02 02:00:00+00, 'txt3'
```

- client 2

```
2015-12-02 03:00:00+00, 'txt4'
2015-12-02 05:00:00+00, 'txt5'
```

- client 3

```
2015-12-02 16:00:00+00, 'txt6'
2015-12-02 23:00:00+00, 'txt7'
```

The question:
How can I create BRIN with predefined number of partitions and run queries which filters on partition identifiers instead of filtering on index column?
Optionally any other way that BRIN (or other pg goodies) can speed up the task of parallel loading multiple clients from single table?

Comment: This might be more successful on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Multiple clients mean multiple sessions. I don't think you can split your table (almost) evenly in a concurrency-safe way (with any index). Or is that off the table? BTW why not a classic [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)? (In PostgreSQL, you can actually query for a single partition.) -- never mind, I see: client numbers may vary.

Comment: @pozs the hard assumption is there is no writes to table while it is being queried as both processes are run sequentially in the workflow. BRIN looks perfect for that use case: load data, create brin, analyze table, and then run queries.

Comment: Q: Do all (client) machines know how many partitions there are supposed to be the moment you start ? In other words, suppose you start the process on day n with x machines, you want your table evenly split over x partitions, right? But on day x+1 you might have y machines and hence want it split over y partitions. My question then is: when a client machine connects, does it *know* it wants 1/x or 1/y of the table?

Comment: @deroby no, inside the clients there is just an unique integer sequence, so they just know which bucket to chose. Buckets needs to be provided on db side. Master client process knows how much node there is so can create table as select and calculate buckets, but this seems to be inefficient vs. using underlying brin partitioning.

Comment: Have you verified that the result won't be I/O-bound or Ethernet-bound, thereby making the procedure of no benefit?

Comment: `row_number() over (order by datetime) % N` would put every `N`th row into a bucket (as opposed to the 1st N rows, 2nd rows, etc as it is in your example). For example, the first group would be 1,4,7 not 1,2,3

Comment: @FuzzyTree it doesn't matter much as `row_number() over ()` is poor workaround for what BRIN, if exposed enough, could give.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to shard a table over many machines, and have each local table (one shard of the global table) have a BRIN index with exactly one bucket.  But that does not make any sense.  If the single BRIN index range covers the entire (local) table, then it can never be very helpful.

It sounds like what you are looking for is partitioning with CHECK constraints that can be used for partition-exclusion.  PostgreSQL has supported that for a long time with table inheritance (although not for each partition being on a separate machine).  Using this method, the range covered in the CHECK constraint has to be set explicitly for each partition.  This ability to explicitly specify the bounds sounds like it exactly what you are looking for, just using a different technology.

But, the partition exclusion constraint code doesn't work well with modulus.  The code is smart enough to know that `WHERE id=5` only needs to check the `CHECK (id BETWEEN 1 and 10)` partition, because it knows that id=5 implies that id is between 1 and 10.  More accurately, it know that contrapositive of that.

But the code was never written to know that `WHERE id=5` implies that `id%10 = 5%10`, even though humans know that.  So if you build your partitions on modulus operators, like `CHECK (id%10=5)` rather than on ranges, you would have to sprinkle all your queries with `WHERE id = $1 and id % 10= $1 %10` if you wanted it to take advantage of the constraints.

Comment: physical partitioning is the best way to address that, is there a dynamic way to create (partitioned) table as select? so I could user `row_number() over ()` to prepare partitions on database side?

Answer (score 0):

Going by your description and comments I'd say you're looking in the wrong direction. You want to split the table upfront so access will be fast and simple, but without having to split things upfront because that would require you know the number of nodes upfront which is kind of variable if I understand correctly. And regardless, it takes quite a bit of processing to split things too.

To be honest, I'd go about your problem differently. Instead of assigning every record to a bucket I'd rather suggest to assign every record a pseudo-random value in a given range. I don't know about Postgres but in MSSQL I'd use `BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID())` instead of `Rand()`. Main reason being that the random function is harder to use SET-based there. Instead you could also use some hashing code that returns a reasonable working space. Anyway, in my MSSQL situation the resulting value would then be a signed integer sitting somewhere in the range -2^31 to +2^31 (giver or take, check the documentation for the exact boundaries!). As such, when the master machine decides to assign n client-machines, each machine can be assigned an exact range that -- given the properties of the randomizer/hashing algo -- will envelope a reasonably close approximation to the workload divided by n. 
Assuming you have an index on the selection field this should be reasonably fast, regardless whether you decide to split the table in a thousand or a million chunks.

PS: mind that this approach will only work 'properly' if number of rows to process (greatly) outnumbers the number of machines that will do the processing. With small numbers you might see several machines not getting anything while others get to do all the work.

Comment: You understand correctly. It could take as much processing as creating brin, isn't it? Your proposed solution doesn't look to be efficient, at least as well as create brin. Selection by index would be fast but would not scale same good as direct access to partitioned data - which I would like to achieve with brin.

Comment: Feel free to disagree, but IMHO an arbitrary selection by index will easily outperform the extra time you'll spent splitting up your table (which from what I read in the help on BRIN indexes is what you'll need to do upfront). I have no experience with BRIN indexes, but from the help they look a lot like some sort of (lossy) partitions. I'm all pro partitioning, but don't expect to split a table from 20 partitions into 25 partitions or vice versa in the blink of an eye, you'll be heavily disappointed.

Comment: AFAIK you can create brin directly on a table without any upfront preparation.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with BRIN indexes, but you want the index to handle the 'you're part of block 5' situation, right? Then you somehow need to pre-define which records are part of block 5 (by creating the index based on some field value). If there will be X client machines today but tomorrow there will Y, this means you'll need to re-define the bucketing and thus recreate the index 'overnight'. If the BRIN really 'holds all relevant records' together on disk, this might cause the need for some moving around of the data. The fetch later on might be fast, the preparation will not be.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, all you need to know is the size of the relation after loading, and then the `pages_per_range` storage parameter should be set to the divisor that gives you the desired number of partitions.

No need to introduce an artificial partition ID, because there is support for sufficient types and operators. Physical table layout *is* important here, so if you insist on the partition ID being the key, and end up introducing an out-of-order mapping between the natural load order and the artificial partition ID, make sure you cluster the table on that column's sort order before creating BRIN.

However, at the same time, remember that more discrete values have a better chance of hitting the index than fewer, so high cardinality is better - artificial partition identifier will have 1/n the cardinality of a natural key, where n is the number of distinct values per partition.

More [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/brin-intro.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/brin-builtin-opclasses.html).

Comment: *No need to introduce an artificial partition ID* - so how to query data into equal chunks without guessing values of indexed column? or their distribution so I can guess range in chunks? I'm familiar with the pg documentation but it doesn't answer my question, neither do your answer.

Comment: Well then the answer is BRIN is not what you want. In terms of values, it is non-discriminatory and it just splits the entire range into equal size blocks. It will help you hit less pages in a sequential scan (as any index will), but that is it. It can not tell you what to search for.

Comment: But from the logical point of view it could, and it basically a matter of exporting an API for partitions id. Maybe internals are available somewhere but not yet documented.

Comment: You could try making some sense out of it by using the ctid pseudo-column extensively (which returns (page, record) positions for any record in a table). What you'll probably find though, is that your solution has nothing to do with BRIN except the key condition - to have naturally clustered data (which you do, timestamps). I guess with x pages in table, partition m of n could be doing a query "where ctid between ((m-1)*(x/n)) and (m*(x/n))". Since this directly relates to table structure though, you need no additional objects.

Comment: Note that the [page number has to be extracted](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers) from ctid in the where clause.